# Unable to load libhdfs when using pyarrow

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I'm trying to connect to HDFS through Pyarrow, but it does not work because `libhdfs` library cannot be loaded.

`libhdfs.so` is in `$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native` as well as in `$ARROW_LIBHDFS_DIR`.

```
print(os.environ['ARROW_LIBHDFS_DIR'])
fs = hdfs.connect()


bash-3.2$ ls $ARROW_LIBHDFS_DIR
examples        libhadoop.so.1.0.0  libhdfs.a       libnativetask.a
libhadoop.a     libhadooppipes.a    libhdfs.so      libnativetask.so
libhadoop.so        libhadooputils.a    libhdfs.so.0.0.0    libnativetask.so.1.0.0
```

The error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wine-pred-ml.py", line 31, in <module>
    fs = hdfs.connect()
  File "/Users/PVZP/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pyarrow/hdfs.py", line 183, in connect
    extra_conf=extra_conf)
  File "/Users/PVZP/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pyarrow/hdfs.py", line 37, in __init__
    self._connect(host, port, user, kerb_ticket, driver, extra_conf)
  File "pyarrow/io-hdfs.pxi", line 89, in pyarrow.lib.HadoopFileSystem._connect
  File "pyarrow/error.pxi", line 83, in pyarrow.lib.check_status
pyarrow.lib.ArrowIOError: Unable to load libhdfs
```

Comment: Solved by using Conda to install libhdfs3 and pyarrow rather than trying to build it myself or using the libhdfs prepackaged with Hadoop.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. Can you share more details? I installed libhdfs3 using conda and put `driver='libhdfs3` but still get "Unable to load libhdfs3". What am I missing?

Comment: I also would like to know how you solved this, Pablo.

Answer (score 3):

This solves my issue:

```
conda install libhdfs3 pyarrow
```

in your script.py:

```
import os
os.environ['ARROW_LIBHDFS_DIR'] = '/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib64/'
```

where the path is the directory in which libhdfs3 lives - in my case this is where Cloudera hosts the lib

Comment: How can I pip install this instead?

Comment: simply use anaconda ;)

Comment: but I can't in this environment unfortunately, I found the libhdfs.so file elswhere already installed tho